# Catching URLs with GET parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

I have and old Wordpress website. It had URLs like:

`/?wpsc-product=abc`

I have built a new website in Django, with URLs like:

`/products/abc/`

How can I catch old URLs and redirect them to new ones? Actually, I'm not sure how can I catch URL with parameters.

I'd like to be able to write every single redirection, instead of making regular expression, since I didn't keep all the slugs, some of them are changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't catch GET parameters like `?wpsc-product=abc` in your `urls.py`, but you can write a view that checks for GET parameters and redirects to the new view.

Here is a simplified urls.py with two views. The index view redirects requests with parameters and redirects them (e.g. `/?wpsc-product=abc`), and also handles requests without any parameters (i.e. `/`, and returns the rendered index template.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.view_product, name='view_product'),
]

from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def index(request):
    # check for wpsc-product in GET params
    if 'wpsc-product' in request.GET:
        return redirect('view_product', slug=request.GET['wpsc-product'])
    else:
        # return the regular index template
        return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Comment: This is partial answer, since the URL is redirected to the same slug. It won't work if the slug has changed in the new website. Good idea, anyway.

Comment: You have access to the slug in the view, it's easy to change it if necessary.